# Find a $p \in (0, \infty) $ that assures a uniform bound for a sequence of continous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Let ${v_n}$ be a sequence of continuous functions $v_n: [0. \pi] \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $||v_n||_1 <1$ for all $n>1$. Is it possibile to find a $p_0 \in (1, \infty)$ such that $||v_n||_{p_0}< \infty $ for all $n>1$?

My attempt was to try to use the continuity of the map $p \mapsto ||v||p$ for a fixed $v$, but this seem to fail in finding the uniform bound requested.

Comment: There is a positive function $f(x)$ continuous on $(0,\pi]$ such that $f\in L^1$ but $f\notin L^p$ for any $p>1.$ The sequence $v_n(x)=f(x)$ for ${1\over n}\le x\le \pi$ and $v_n(x)=f({1\over n})$ for $0\le x\le {1\over n}$ satisfies $\|v_n\|_p\to \infty $ for any $p>1,$ and $\|v_n\|_1\to \|f\|_1.$

Comment: I see, thank you